# View the LED driver signal on the ground and op-amp output

Tags: led, ground, grounding, led-driver

I create a simple LED driver and op-amp circuit. I used a mid-IR LED with a 200 mV voltage and 1A current. A 2 kHz signal is input to the LED driver and Surprisingly, this signal is observed on the ground and at the output of the op-amp, causing a distortion in the photodiode signal.

- Is this problem due to the high current of the LED?
- How to remove the LED signal on the ground?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP5j6P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "Observed on the ground" - How are you measuring ? How is the circuit constructed (proper PCB or breadboard or ... ? )

Comment: Measuring by oscilloscope between power supply ground and  PCB ground.

Comment: Are you using a low inductance ground clip on your probe? You might be chasing ghosts.